# combining all the javascript file into one file

Tags: javascript, php, html, performance, web

i want to optimise the performance of my website, it is taking too much time to load, i've been searching for some tips since a while, one of the tips is to combine all the javascript files into a unique one, i'm not an expert in js, could someone explain how can i combine them? should i put all the content in one file and call it at the end of my HTML? if there is any tutorial, it would be great for me if someone gives me the link
thanks

Comment: Google could have thousands of solutions for you. Sorry

Comment: This might help: [grunt-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)

Comment: i'm looking for this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Though the way you asked the question is not correct so please go through guidelines once.

You can use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for your job.